# Firebase Rules con auth.uid

Tags: firebase, autenticación

Leyendo la documentación de firebase me di cuenta que podía modificar las reglas para que solo se tuviera acceso especifico a cada usuario en una rama en particular.

```
{
 "rules": {
  "users": {
   "$uid": {
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  } 
}
```

Pero yo no encuentro la manera correcta de hacerlo, esta es mi data en firebase.

[image: authUid es el id que genera al crear un usuario authenticado con firebase]

(suponiendo que authUid es el Auth.uid que genera al autentificarse con firebase)

estas son mis reglas en ese lugar en especifico, todas las demás son publicas

```
 "usuarios": {
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
  },
```

¿Como puedo hacer que mi regla sea valida utilizando $uid en mis reglas, para que solo entre el usuario a su correspondiente rama y no entre a ramas de otros usuarios?

Comment: Por si no quedo claro quiero que a mi rama de usuarios solo pueda acceder el que coincida con su uid, y no pueda entrar a ningún  otro usuario

Answer (score 1):

Regla que usa la variable `auth` para garantizar que cada usuario solo pueda escribir en una ruta específica, la del mismo usuario:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Si desea restringir el acceso a estos datos de manera que solo el usuario que ha iniciado sesión pueda ver sus propios datos, sus reglas se verían de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

En la [documentación oficial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) se puede encontrar más información al respecto.